# Javascript self invoking function issue (Behat/Mink/Sahi)

Tags: javascript, jquery, behat, mink, sahi

I'm currently at a loss to why this is occurring, but I wouldn't be surprised if I was either way off, or missing one tiny little thing.

**Here's my code:**

```
(function() { 
    if (jQuery('section.news-feed ul li').text().length > 0) {
        var length1 = parseInt(jQuery('section.news-feed ul li').text().length); 
        var length2 = 0; 

        setTimeout(function() {
            length2 = parseInt(jQuery('section.news-feed ul li').text().length); 

            if (length1 !== length2) {
                return true;
            } 
            else {
                return false;
            }

        }, 3000);
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
})()
```

**I'm looking for a boolean return, although, I'm receiving 'undefined'.** The jQuery specific selectors are correct and I find length1 and length2 correctly.

To further add to the question encase there's someone with Behat/Mink/Sahi experience, this is what I'm looking to do:

**Behat:**

```
@javascript
    Scenario: News ticker is moving
    Given I am on the homepage
    Then I should see the news ticker "section.news-feed ul li" move
```

**Context:**

```
/**
 * @Then /^I should see the news ticker "([^"]*)" move$/
 */
public function iShouldSeeTheNewsTickerMove($element) {
    $result = $this
                ->getSession()
                ->evaluateScript("
                    (function() { 
                        if (jQuery('" . $element . "').text().length > 0) {
                            var length1 = parseInt(jQuery('" . $element . "').text().length); 
                            var length2; 

                            setTimeout(function() {
                                var length2 = parseInt(jQuery('" . $element . "').text().length); 

                                if (length1 !== length2) {
                                    return true;
                                } 
                                else {
                                    return false;
                                }

                            }, 3000);
                        }
                        else {
                            return false;
                        } 
                    })()
                ");

    echo "Result: " . $result;

    if ($result === 'false') {
        throw new Exception (
            "The newws ticker doesn't seem to be ticking."
        );
    }

}
```

Comment: yeah, `setTimeout()` returns a timer handle, not the return value of whatever function it invokes.

Comment: @roasted aahh I see his problem now.. I posted that comment after skimming through the code and thought he wanted the handler (integer) back to the caller else `false`.

Answer (score 2):

when your `if` block evaluates to true, your top-level anonymous function does not return any value.  You're scheduling a function to be run after some period of time, and then that's it.  The function you schedule to run DOES always return a boolean, but your top-level anonymous function does not.

Since you're already using jQuery, I'd suggest using its [Deferred](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) feature to solve your problem.  Briefly, your top-level function will return, instead of a boolean (or undefined! :), a promise that it's going to do some job.  When the promise is fulfilled, either immediately or after the call to `setTimeout()` runs, you're guaranteed to have a boolean value waiting for you.

```
(function() {
    function foo() {
      var deferred = $.Deferred();

      if (jQuery('section.news-feed ul li').text().length > 0) {
          var length1 = parseInt(jQuery('section.news-feed ul li').text().length); 
          var length2 = 0; 

          setTimeout(function() {
              length2 = parseInt(jQuery('section.news-feed ul li').text().length); 

              if (length1 !== length2) {
                  //return true;
                  deferred.resolve(true);
              } 
              else {
                  //return false;
                  deferred.resolve(false);
              }

          }, 3000);
      }
      else {
          //return false;
          deferred.resolve(false);
      }

      return (deferred.promise());
    }

    foo().done(function(myBoolean) {
        alert(myBoolean);
    });
})()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick reply! My mind really isn't in it tonight. What would I ideally change to fix the issue?

Comment: you're already using jQuery, so I would use jQuery's Deferred feature to solve this.  It's easier to explain with code than text, so let me update my answer for you.

Comment: oh, hey.  I'm messing up my JavaScript with my Behat/Mink, but hopefully you get the idea.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll give it a whirl and let you know. I really appreciate the help!

Comment: Unfortunately I'm still receiving 'undefined' as initial output, and then 'true' 3 seconds later. The issue is likely to do with the mink processing where it takes the first answer through evaluateScript() regardless. Very awkward issue that I'm really not sure how to get around.